# pandas concat two dataframe while one column concat and another one still keeps?

Tags: python, pandas

**Input**

```
df1

id      date      v1
a    2020-1-1     1
a    2020-1-2     2
b    2020-1-4     10
b    2020-1-22    30
c    2020-2-4     10
c    2020-2-22    30


df2

id      date      v1
a    2020-1-3     1
b    2020-1-7     12
b    2020-1-22    13
c    2020-2-10    15
c    2020-2-22    60
```

**Goal**

```
id      date      v1   v2
a    2020-1-1     1    0
a    2020-1-2     2    0
a    2020-1-3     0    1
b    2020-1-4     10   0
b    2020-1-7     0    12
b    2020-1-22    30   13
c    2020-2-4     10   0
c    2020-2-10     0   15
c    2020-2-22    30   60
```

The details:

- Only two dataframes, for each `id`, the date is unique.
- Concat two dataframes into `df` based on `id`, each `id` contains all date values from two dataframe
- new merge dataframe contains v1 and v2 columns, while the date in `df1` and `df2`, it returns original values, while the date only in one of `df1` and `df2`, it returns original value and 0 if there is no value on the date.

**Try**
I have searched merge, concat document but I could not find the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert columns to datetimes for correct ordering by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with outer join and rename column `v1` for `df2` for avoid `v1_x` and `v1_y` columns in output, replace missing values by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), sorting output by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])

df = (df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'v1':'v2'}), on=['id','date'], how='outer')
         .fillna(0)
         .sort_values(['id','date']))
print (df)
  id       date    v1    v2
0  a 2020-01-01   1.0   0.0
1  a 2020-01-02   2.0   0.0
6  a 2020-01-03   0.0   1.0
2  b 2020-01-04  10.0   0.0
7  b 2020-01-07   0.0  12.0
3  b 2020-01-22  30.0  13.0
4  c 2020-02-04  10.0   0.0
8  c 2020-02-10   0.0  15.0
5  c 2020-02-22  30.0  60.0
```

Comment: @Jack - sure, give me a sec.

Comment: I don't know why using astype because v1 and v2 could be the float.

Comment: @Jack - If should be floats only remove `.astype({'v1':int, 'v2':int})`

Comment: I don't know why using rename before merge, could you explain more?

Comment: @Jack - only for avoid `v1_x` and `v1_y` columns ;)